# Need a currency converter in a Laravel website

Tags: laravel

I am working on a website, and I need a dynamic currency converter. This [reference website link](https://bookretreats.com/28-day-200-hour-hathaashtangakundalini-ttc-in-karnataka-india) is what I actually want on my website.

Comment: You might want this https://github.com/moneyphp/money

Comment: but how can i implement this package in my project code...please suggest me,i have urgent need this a currency converter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple of packages available :

Best one :[moneyphp/money](https://github.com/moneyphp/money)
Alternatives : 
[Torann/laravel-currency](https://github.com/Torann/laravel-currency)
[akaunting/money](https://github.com/akaunting/money)

However, you can actually find these and some more on your own. If you do not find these from google search, [packagist](https://packagist.org) can be the place to search for a package using keyword like `money`, `currency` in this case and you see downloads, versions and github links etc.

Comment: but how can i implement this package in my project code...please suggest me,i have urgent need this a currency converter.

Comment: You can install any package in laravel using composer. Search for the the package you want and using `compose require package/name` you can install and directly use it. Most of the packages will have the installation and usage instructions.